# ERD in Netbeans 7.3

Tags: erd, netbeans-platform

How can I create ERD (entity relationship diagram) in Netbeans ? I installed ERD plugin, but dont know how to use in, where to find this function. I need to create ERD and then generate SQL script.
Thanks

Comment: Which "ERD plugin" are you talking about? Doesn't it come with a manual or help?

Comment: extend your question please

Comment: try https://www.erdcloud.com

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are talking about "Entity Relationship Diagram Support" (Org.netbeans.erdbeans73.nbm). In this case unfortunately the plugin doesn't support the manual creation of ER Diagram. It only takes a database schema and automatically generates an ER Diagram. Do do that you have to go in "new file" -> "persistence" -> "ER-Diagram" and follow the wizard.